# PHP - Insert to Database Using Another Table

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-insert

I make 2 forms in 3 files: `loginMHS.php`, `inputPerwalian.php`, `insertMataKuliah.php`.

I have 4 tables in database: `mahasiswa`, `matakuliah`, `kelas`, `mahasiswa_kelas`.

`mahasiswa` table has these fields:

`nrp | nama | pass | jatah_sks | foto_profil`

`matakuliah` table has these fields:

`kode_mk | nama | jumlah_sks | deskripsi`

`kelas` table has these fields:

`kode_kelas | kode_mk | kode_periode | nama_kelas`

`mahasiswa_kelas` table has these fields:

`nrp | kode_kelas`

First, `loginMHS.php` showed up. It has a form, which has an input stored in var `$nrp` (from `mahasiswa` table). After login, `inputPerwalian.php` showed up. It has a form too, which has inputs stored in var `$kodeMK` (from `matakuliah` table) & `$namaKelas` (from `kelas` table). Then, the inputs will be inserted to table `mahasiswa_kelas`.

This is my code (the inputs can't be stored to DB, but it shows no error):

```
$sql = "select kode_kelas from kelas inner join mahasiswa_kelas"
       . " on kelas.kode_kelas = mahasiswa_kelas.kode_kelas"
       . " where nama_kelas=" . $namaKelas;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$sql2 = "insert into mahasiswa_kelas (nrp, kode_kelas)"
        . " values ($nrp, $result)";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
```

I don't know how to insert it, while the data inputed is from another table. Because, from what I know is, I can't use inner join in insert query. How to solve it? Please explain your answer. Thanks

Comment: What is the type of kode_kelas in mahasiswa_kelas table?  Look at what mysqli_query returns into $result with a var_dump.

Comment: @NicholasAlexander The type is int

Comment: mysql_query should return FALSE on error (i.e. an int) or a resource that can be used to get results: see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php - I think you are being tripped up by a returned error condition but I strongly encourage understanding is the real answer here.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query()` returns an object so you can't insert `$result` as a value. Check out how they handle it in the manual with [mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) This should take care of your problem

Update:
Not sure what you mean by 'use' but I think not . . . keep reading. You need to parse your array from `mysqli_fetch_row()`. Look at

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

/* fetch associative array */ 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]); 
} 
free result set */ mysqli_free_result($result);

}`
```

Update 2:
Not sure if I should be writing the code for you but here you go. As described `mysqli_query()` returns $result as an object. `mysqli_fetch_row()` returns $result as an array. Get your value from the proper array index and assign to a variable `$kode_kelas_value`. Insert that variable into the db with your $sql2 query.

```
$sql = "select kode_kelas from kelas inner join mahasiswa_kelas"
       . " on kelas.kode_kelas = mahasiswa_kelas.kode_kelas"
       . " where nama_kelas=" . $namaKelas;
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $kode_kelas_value = $row[0];
    } 
    /*free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);

}`

    $sql2 = "insert into mahasiswa_kelas (nrp, kode_kelas)"
            . " values ($nrp, $kode_kelas_value)";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
```

Comment: So, can I use this? `mixed mysqli_fetch_row ( mysqli_result $result )`

Comment: Just to clarify mysqli_query() returns an object. mysqli_fetch_row() 'Get a result row as an enumerated array'. The data you're trying to insert is in the elements of the array so, loop the array, assign the the values to variables and insert those variables into your db with $sql2. There are more efficient ways to do it but editing your method this is what you ned to do.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still confused with this. So, can you please update your answer & answer my question directly? Then, explain from your code. Maybe, I can understand more with that way. Thanks

Comment: Your code has no error, but the inputed data still aren't stored to database

Comment: use var_dump($result); and  var_dump($row);  to see what's in those values. it seems you may not have any results from $sql.

Comment: This might also help you out: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-handle-result-from-mysqli-query/6009

Comment: var_dump($result) and var_dump($row) didn't show any result. And the link that you gave to me, sorry but, it doesn't help me.

Comment: If your original $sql query and var_dump($result) from  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql); doesn't yield any result the problem is either your connection or your query. Check your connection and try running your query directly on the database and see what you get.

Comment: The problem is my query. And I can't try it on the database, because I don't know what the right query is.

Comment: What's the query error? I think you need to research the sql and if you can't figure it out start a new question. I'm doing too much of the work for you which I don't think is what the point is here. But at least we narrowed it down.

Comment: If I run it on my program, it shows no sql error, just there are no result showed. And I can't run it on database, because it contains of 2 queries, since I can't use variable on database. Yeah, thanks for your help, but sorry, I can't upvote you, because it didn't work. The link can't help me. Because, my problem is more complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113233/discussion-between-dg4220-and-grace-michelle).

Answer (score 0):

you should fetch nrp, kode_kelas values by using join query. If you got those values perfectly then you can insert simply know. Any queries ask me.

Comment: Can you give a more specific answer? Maybe you can answer my question directly?

Comment: i answered in next answer

Answer (score 0):

First you can get nrp value from loginMHS.php. You have to pass that nrp value to inputPerwalian.php. In inputPerwalian.php you can get value for kodemk. if you submit that form u will get 2 important needed data that are nrp and kodemk. Now u would have nrp and kodemk.

now you have to insert into mahasiswa_kelas with nrp, kode_kelas. Already you have nrp, but u dont have kode_kelas. in order to get kode_kelas value you have to select kode_kelas data from kelas table by select query.

```
"SELECT kode_kelas FROM kelas where kode_mk = kodemk "
```

By using this query you can get kode_kelas value.

Now you can insert nrp and kode_kelas values in mahasiswa_kelas.

Hope it will helpful.